# Spring AOP Aspect not executing

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, aspects

I've been trying to figure out why my simple aspect is not getting executed.  I looked at the answers of similar problems but i still can't get it to work.

My intention is to wrap the execution of a method annotated with a custom annotation with an AOP advice that will track how long the method takes to run.  When i run my test, i see the output of the method but the advice is not being run (i'm expecting it to log some output).

Here's the Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
class LatencyProfiler {

    private LatencyTrackerFactory factory = LatencyTrackerFactory.NOOP;

    @Pointcut(value="execution(@ProfileLatency * *(..)) && @annotation(annotation)", argNames="annotation")
    public void profiled(ProfileLatency annotation) {}

    @Around(value="profiled(annotation)", argNames="pjp,annotation")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, ProfileLatency annotation) throws Throwable {

        ILatencyTracker tracker;

        try {
            tracker = factory.create(annotation.trackerName(), annotation.trackerNameSuffix());
        } catch (ConfigException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        tracker.begin();
        Object ret = pjp.proceed();
        tracker.end(null);

        return ret;
    }

   @Optional
    public void setFactory(LatencyTrackerFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
}
```

Followed by the Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ProfileLatency {
    String trackerName();
    String trackerNameSuffix() default"[unassigned]";
}
```

Followed by a test class:

```
public class Test {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(Test.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
                            foo();
                            LOG.info("HERE");
                        }
                    }
                }, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }

    @ProfileLatency(trackerName = "latency", trackerNameSuffix = "s")
    public void foo() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="latencyProfileAspect"/>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<bean
    id    = "latencyLogger"
    class = "util.logging.LatencyLogger"
/>

<bean
    id    = "trackerFactory"
    class = "util.latency.LatencyTrackerFactoryImpl">
    <constructor-arg value = "config/latency-config.xml"/>
    <constructor-arg ref   = "latencyLogger"/>
</bean>

<bean
    id            = "latencyProfileAspect"
    class         = "util.latency.aop.LatencyProfiler"
    p:factory-ref = "trackerFactory"
/>

<bean id = "test" class="util.Test"/>
```

and finally the test's output:

```
21:20:37,930 INFO  main/SpringMain - Ready.
21:20:40,928 INFO  pool-4-thread-1/Test - HERE
21:20:41,927 INFO  pool-4-thread-1/Test - HERE
21:20:42,926 INFO  pool-4-thread-1/Test - HERE
21:20:43,925 INFO  pool-4-thread-1/Test - HERE
21:20:44,924 INFO  pool-4-thread-1/Test - HERE
...
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So i fiddled with this around a bit and got it to work.  I modified the aspect as follows:

```
@Aspect
public class LatencyProfiler {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(LatencyProfiler.class);

    @Around("@annotation(annotation)")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, ProfileLatency annotation) throws Throwable {

        ILatencyTracker tracker = ILatencyTracker.NOOP;

        try {
            tracker = StaticLatencyTrackerFactory.getTracker(annotation.trackerName(), annotation.trackerNameSuffix());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }

        LatencyContext ctx = tracker.beginContext();
        Object ret = pjp.proceed();
        ctx.end();

        return ret;
    }

    /*
     *  special purpose factory method
     */
    public static LatencyProfiler aspectOf() {
        return MyAspectHolder.instance;
    }

    /**
     * private class holding the singleton
     */
    private static class MyAspectHolder {
        static final LatencyProfiler instance = new LatencyProfiler();
    }
}
```

i also changed the spring configuration to be:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

<bean
    id             = "latencyProfileAspect"
    class          = "util.latency.aop.LatencyProfiler"
    factory-method = "aspectOf"
/>

<bean id = "test" class="util.Test"/>
```